# Filtering Search Query with AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a music store type of application and I use php to get images and names of specific musical instruments from a database. I want to incorporate a search bar that dynamically filters the musical instruments, and I want to use AngularJS to do this. I'm having trouble after creating the $watch in AngularJS. I know how to filter using a JS object, but I am having trouble with this scenario.

I am assuming I could create a JS object from the `innerHTML` from the required elements. Then I could use an `ng-repeat` to filter through the object based on what is in the input search box. Is that a valid option? If so are there any other options available?

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div ng-controller="instController">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="search-instrument-wrapper">
  <input class="searchbar" type="text" ng-model="searchInst" placeholder="Search Instruments"/>
  </div>

<?php foreach ($instruments as $singleInstrument) : ?>
  <div class="col-md-4 instrument-wrapper">
   <a href='instruments/<?php echo $singleInstrument; ?>.php#/'>
    <span class="inst-thumbnail">     
    <img class="img-responsive instrument-images" src="images/<?php echo $singleInstrument; ?>"/>     
    </span>
   </a>
   <a href='instrument/<?php echo $singleInstrument ?>/<?php echo $singleInstrument ?>.php#/'>
   <h3 class="instrumentName"><?php echo $instrumentInfo['instrumentName'];?></h3>
   </a>  
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**AngularJS**

```
instApp.controller('instController',['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.searchInst = '';
   $scope.$watch('searchInst',function(newVal,oldVal){    
     /*** MY ATTEMPT ***/
        if(!$( ".instrumentName:contains('"+newVal+"')" )){
                   $(this).parent().css( "display",
        "none" );}
     /******************/
   });
}]);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the problem you are having.

Comment: I think you are thinking of Angular a little too much like jQuery. The correct method here would be to use `ng-repeat` with a json dataset.

Comment: I updated my question with stating that could be an option. I think the inclusion of the PHP is throwing me off a little bit. Maybe I could just use a json_encode to encode the Database object somehow? Or just manually loop through the Database object and store it into a JSON format for use of `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out doing it the way that was described in the comments:

The key is to post your data from the database into a `foreach` loop and concatenate a string to create a JSON object. Then use `ng-init` to initialize the JSON for the `ng-repeat` to use. Works for me

**PHP**

```
foreach($instrumentsArray as $instruments){

$jsonStatement .= '{
               name:"' . $instrumentInfo['instrumentName'] . '"' .
             ',url: "user/' . $instruments . '/' . $instruments . '.php#/"'. 
             ',img: "user/' . $instruments . '/images/' . $instrumentPicInfo['instrumentPic'] . '"},';                    


$jsonComplete = 'instruments = [' . $jsonStatement . ']';
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init='<?php echo $jsonComplete;?>'></div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="search-instruments">
    <input class="searchbar" type="text" ng-model="searchinstruments"  placeholder="Search Instruments"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 instrumentWrapper" ng-repeat="instrument in instruments | filter: searchinstruments">
     <a href='{{instrument.url}}'>
       <span class="instruments-thumbnail">     
         <img class="img-responsive user-images" src="{{instrument.img}}"/>       
       </span></a>
     <a href='{{instrument.url}}'><h3 class="instrumentName">{{instrument.name}}</h3></a>  
</div>
```